# apply_filters (how to remove this filter already added) - woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to remove a filter that sets the template of my results, in this case, it uses UL to organize the content. I don't need this.

- Case 1) Remove this and my code takes care os the layout
- Case 2) Apply another filter to set my own template.

**woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widgets-products.php**

- line 192

```html
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' );
```

- line 199

```html
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_after_widget_product_list', '</ul>');
```

There is another element that comes from the hook, but this one I couldn't found the place it comes from, my rendered html shows it:

```
<div class="listaprodutos"><h2 class="widgettitle">Produtos</h2>
<ul class="product_list_widget">
```

My goal is remove all these two settings (**widgettitle** and **product_list_widget**).

I add this lines in my functions.php page, but it didn't work:

```
// Remove UL format for products_widget

remove_filter( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' );
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_after_widget_product_list', '</ul>' );
```

front-page.php

```
<p class="display-4" style="text-align:center">Produtos mais vendidos</p>

<div class="container">

      <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'listaprodutos' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'listaprodutos' ); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

content-widget-product.php

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card" style="width: 19rem; margin-bottom:3rem; margin-top:3rem;">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src=<?php echo $product->get_image(); ?> 

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $product->get_name(); ?></h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-quick" href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ); ?>">Ler o post</a>
              </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've the same question. Did you solve it?

Comment: @ata do you have a question that I can see? I've found some ways to solve it, but if you could explain your problem I'd help you.

Comment: I've an `apply_filters` in my code. This is not in WooCommerce but I want this `apply_filter` does not act just like your question. I would be grateful if you tell me how you handled your situation maybe give me an idea.

Comment: Please post your solution if you have solved it

Comment: @tellmewhy There is no solution yet, but I changeg to the class "card" and it works for now. 
see http://www.quickgamestore.ml